Netlink wakes up my PC?
I have activated wakeonlan on my Linux Mint machine, and it works fine.
Even too fine, whenever I shut down the machine, it will reboot after anything from 10 secs to 10 minutes.
I've activated logging and deactivated some USB devices, and all I can find are netlink events that are responsible for the wakeup. The PC is connected via eth0.
These are the entries in syslog:

kernel: [    0.136838] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
kernel: [    0.535922] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
kernel: [    0.575244] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM egments MSI EDR HPX-Type3]
kernel: [    0.575446] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [SHPCHotplug LTR DPC]
kernel: [0.575639] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
kernel: [    0.575650] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
kernel: [    0.612601] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
kernel: [1.669226] acpi_cpufreq: overriding BIOS provided _PSD data
acpid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
acpid: 8 rules loaded
acpid: waiting for events: event logging is on
acpid: client connected from 1903[0:0]
acpid: 1 client rule loaded

Is there any way to find out which device in my network sends these magic packets to my PC?
